# SQOOP IMPORT AND EVAL

Tags: hive, hiveql, sqoop, bigdata

I have a view on SQL server and the view on X DB is joined with table on Y DB.If I try to access this View from SQOOP using SQL server connection rferencing X DB, I am unable to get the results but If I move the data from Y DB to X DB and chnage the view to refer both the tables in XDB I see the results.

How can I overcome this problem because It's not possible to bring more than 100 tables from Y to X DB.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the SQL server side with permissions.

Thank you.